# Convert WSAGetLastError to an std::exception?

Tags: c++, sockets, exception

I'm writing a simple sockets program, and I'd like to throw an error in some cases, to make catching the error easier. To get the error, I'm using `WSAGetLastError()`. This only returns the code associated with the error, which I cannot throw, since throwing an error requires an `std::exception`. Is there any function I could use to convert the result from `WSAGetLastError()` to an `std::exception` which I can throw? Or are there any better methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, no, `throw 42;` is perfectly valid.  Do not throw std::exception, very high odds that you want to catch it because socket errors are not unusual.  Just derive your own class from std::exception.  Use FormatMessage() to get a string.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks I'll try that :)

Comment: @ExcessPhase Even if, this is no reason for such insults. And I think you don't even know that deletions can happen without any moderator...

Comment: @deviantfan -- there is sufficient reason to mention a fact. Potentially this can cause other "moderators" avoid such problems in the first place.

Comment: since my comment was deleted by some ... "moderator" I'm adding it here again: Some years ago I asked essentially the same question. This questions were deleted by some ... "moderators". I still do not understand their reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

cannot delete, try to overwrite